# How can i plot an array of numbers in WxMaxima?

Tags: math, wxmaxima

I need to plot all the elements of a[n] 0<=n<=30. Is that possible in maxima?

[These are the numbers i need to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iR7c.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the way, you can help others help you by typing your work so far into your question. That way people can see it immediately instead of having to go look for it.

About plotting the points, remember that `a[n]` as you have defined it is a so-called array function instead of a list or array. The plotting functions can work with lists, I believe. So you need to evaluate your function at a number of points and then plot the points.

Something like: `mypoints: makelist([n, a[n]], n, 1, 30);` to generate the points. Then with the points in hand, there are different ways to plot them. You can try: `plot2d([discrete, mypoints]);` There are other ways; see `wxdraw2d` for example.